# javascript floating value issue with precision floating point more than 6 digits

Tags: javascript, floating-point

Here I am struck with javascript floating values, I need to show actual value for floating point upto 8 decimals,but brower's JS engine convert the value like 0.00000001 to 1e-8.

```js
function toCustomString(numberToFormat) {
            return '' + Number(numberToFormat.toFixed(8).replace(/\,/g, ','));
        };

// Floating value with 6 digits
var value1 = 0.000001;
console.log(toCustomString(value1))


// Floating value with 8 digits
var value2 = 0.00000001;
console.log(toCustomString(value2) + " <-- this is wrong") // I want here output should be 0.00000001

// Floating value with 8 digits but value greate than 0.000001
var value3 = 0.00010000;
console.log(toCustomString(value3))
```

Comment: toFixed(n) converts the floating values to a string with n digits after the comma. i don't see what is wrong according to you.

Comment: @KevinKloet see "console.log(value3.toFixed(8))" actually I am developing method where I can handle these cases in one location, check the edit

Answer (score 0):

If you want full control over your `digits`, take a look at https://github.com/MikeMcl/decimal.js.

If you don't want trailing `0`, then just remove them with a regex:

```js
console.log(
  '"trailing 0":',
  Number("0.00010000").toFixed(8)
);
console.log(
  '"no trailing 0":',
  Number("0.00010000").toFixed(8).replace(/0*$/,'')
);
```

And with `0.0000000001`:

```js
console.log(
  '"trailing 0":',
  Number("0.0000000001").toFixed(8)
);
console.log(
  '"no trailing 0":',
  Number("0.0000000001").toFixed(8).replace(/0*$/,'')
);
```

Comment: In your case what will be the result of `0.0000000001`?

Comment: Well, it would be `0.`, since i only ask for the first 8 digits. If this is a problem, simply replace `/\.$/` with an empty string.

Comment: yeah, you're right. but is that the same result what he really need?